# Reformat date inside string using pandas replace with regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a column of strings like below that contain date information, and I need to add leading zeros to single-digit months and days. I've run into some issues trying to do this purely with `pandas.DataFrame.replace` and regular expressions.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Key':['0123456789_1/2/2019','0123456789_11/23/2019','0145892367_10/2/2019','0145892367_4/13/2019']})

df
Out[323]: 
                     Key
0    0123456789_1/2/2019
1  0123456789_11/23/2019
2   0145892367_10/2/2019
3   0145892367_4/13/2019
```

For the above column, the output I'd want after reformatting would be:

```
                     Key
0  0123456789_01/02/2019
1  0123456789_11/23/2019
2  0145892367_10/02/2019
3  0145892367_04/13/2019
```

By now I've figured out I can do this by splitting the strings:

```
r = df['Key'].str.split('_|/', expand=True)
df2 = r[0] + '_' + r[1].str.zfill(2) + '/' + r[2].str.zfill(2) + '/' + r[3]

df2
Out[333]: 
0    0123456789_01/02/2019
1    0123456789_11/23/2019
2    0145892367_10/02/2019
3    0145892367_04/13/2019
dtype: object
```

...But when I was initially trying to do it with `pandas.DataFrame.replace`, the closest I was able to get was:

```
df2 = df.replace(r'(_|/)([1-9]/)',r'\1 0\2',regex=True)

df2
Out[335]: 
                      Key
0   0123456789_ 01/2/2019
1   0123456789_11/23/2019
2  0145892367_10/ 02/2019
3  0145892367_ 04/13/2019
```

There are two problems with this that I'd like to know more about:

1. In cases like row 0 where both the month and day are single-digit, it only finds the month. How can I get it to match both?
2. I don't want the spaces, but when I try to replace using `r'\10\2'`, of course I get an error because it thinks I'm trying to substitute in group 10, and there is no such group in the first regex. If I try `r'(\1)0\2'`, it works, except it prints the literal parenthesis. Why does it do this, and how can I properly write this so that it prints group 1 immediately followed by a literal zero?

Edit for clarification:
I'm aware I could also fix it by parsing the dates, but I'm specifically interested in the regex solution, as a learning exercise. Also because a single `replace` is much faster for large dataframes.

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, you can use:

```
df.Key=df.Key.str.split("_").str[0]+"_"+pd.to_datetime(df.Key.str.split("_")
            .str[1]).dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
print(df)
```

---

```
                     Key
0  0123456789_01/02/2019
1  0123456789_11/23/2019
2  0145892367_10/02/2019
3  0145892367_04/13/2019
```

Comment: That does work, but I'm trying to understand how to get around the specific issues I encountered using regex. I'd like to be able to use the regex solution for other cases in the future that may not involve dates.

Answer (score 1):

using [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module

```
df['Key'] = df.Key.str.split('_').apply(lambda x: x[0]+'_'+datetime.strptime(x[1], "%m/%d/%Y").strftime("%m/%d/%Y"))
```

**Output**

```
                     Key
0  0123456789_01/02/2019
1  0123456789_11/23/2019
2  0145892367_10/02/2019
3  0145892367_04/13/2019
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm trying to understand how to get around the specific issues I encountered using regex. I'd like to be able to use the regex solution for other cases in the future.

Comment: using datetime or pd.to_datetime like @anky_91 is better acc to my understanding, it covers all the cases since it understands dates but regex dosen't, it might fail in some